# Python incrementing a Dictionary value entry held within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Following on from an earlier question I am having problems trying to increment a dictionary value contained within a list, I had a few other ideas on using Dictionaries but I am not sure if they are possible or advisable?

My first question is is it possible to increment a dictionary key value where the value is contained in a list?

Say I have a dictionary entry...

```
PointsOfInterest = {
'InterestingString1':['String 1 Description', 0], 
'InterestingString2':['String 2 Description', 0],
'InterestingString3':['String 3 Description', 0],}
```

I am scanning a text file looking for strings of interest (represented as the 'key' in the dictionary. When a Key match is found I want to increment the count in the value **list**, in this case the 2nd list entry in the above dictionary.  Is this possible to achieve as I currently get TypeErrors when I run.  The 'String 1 Description' list entry is there so that I can reference it when I am adding to Excel later on, just to keep everything grouped together and to make it easier to expand the script later on, but this seems to be causing issues with my increment method.

The method below works without the list method, e.g. just incrementing a single value without the 'String # Description' entry

```
for k, v in PointsOfInterest.iteritems():
    if k in mypkt.Text:
        PointsOfInterest[k] = PointsOfInterest[k] + 1
```

I have another question similar to the above, but instead of incrementing a value I hope to append the value to a list within a list within a dict!  This may be too much I suspect, but along the lines of the following dict?

```
ValuesOfInterest = {
'AnotherString1':['Short Description1', []], 
'AnotherString2':['Short Description2', []],
'AnotherString3':['Short Description3', []],}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index into the list object too:

```
for k, v in PointsOfInterest.iteritems():
    if k in mypkt.Text:
        PointsOfInterest[k][1] = PointsOfInterest[k][1] + 1
```

or shorter (since you already have `v` referencing the same value):

```
for k, v in PointsOfInterest.iteritems():
    if k in mypkt.Text:
        v[1] += 1
```

The same would apply to appending items to a nested list in the value:

```
for k, v in PointsOfInterest.iteritems():
    if k in mypkt.Text:
        v[1].append(mykt.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters I was nearly there but I was going along the lines of [k][v[1]] +1.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with increasing the counter is with this line:

```
PointsOfInterest[k] = PointsOfInterest[k] + 1
```

You are attempting to add `1` to the list, not the item. You can correct this by adding the list element you are adding to:

```
PointsOfInterest[k][1] = PointsOfInterest[k][1] + 1
```

Your issue with appending is likely the same issue. You need to append to the element in the sublist:

```
ValuesOfInterest[k][1].append(NEWITEM)
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I was trying to be too detailed in my list referencing.